# c structures bit fields

Tags: c, struct

A code snippet is as follows:

```
struct wer
{
unsigned int a:5;
unsigned int:0;
unsigned int b:3;
unsigned int c:2;
unsigned int:0;
}v;
```

I know that all of these are packed bit fields but how to find the storage which would be needed for v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the storage required for `v` using `sizeof(v)`.

Comment: Yes but if we want to calculate it manually how to go about it

Comment: @soul: you have to read your compiler's manual to see how it does the job.  It is all implementation defined (or mostly implementation defined).  I could see that taking 8 bytes; I could see it taking 2 bytes.  I believe that the standard would allow either, and probably some other values.  I don't think the second zero-length field changes the answer.  (On a Mac, GCC 5.1.0 gives a size of 8.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Ok I got it

Comment: if the word size is 16 bits and bits are accomodated from right to left then what would be the storage required for v